# socket.io Connection in Android WebView crashes

Tags: android, socket.io, android-webview

I'm using latest socket.io (4.7.2) in a node.js project behind an nginx reverse proxy. Client connection from desktop and mobile browser is working fine. But: In an Android App with android webview the initialization of the connection is unreliable. Please see this screenshot from Chrome DevTool:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Let's begin at the 2. line: The socket.io connection is initiated via longpolling, after negotiating everything there upgrade to wss is done in the 5. line. There it hangs for ~5000ms (always around 5000ms) and is restarted right at the beginning in line number 6. New connection, new SID and everything goes on and on. In this example after 7 attempts the connection is established. The wss upgrades takes (as it should) just a few ms (after the final upgrade to wss the authentification is done again by http, but you see that the sid persists, this is a normal behaviour in my script).

Sometimes it works just at the first attempt, sometimes I need 2 or 3 attempts and sometimes the connection is never established.

On mobile chrome (same device, same network) it always works at first attempt so I think the failure could be in my Android App - but where?

Thank you for your support.